# python : create new data frame based on existing data frame column ( date )

Tags: python, dataframe, data-visualization

I have a data frame with below values

Have four shifts per day

```
date        shift  ID timeworked(min)
1/1/2017     1     1   20
1/1/2017     1     9   20
1/1/2017     3     2   100
1/2/2017     2     3   30
1/4/2017     3     4   5
1/1/2017     2     5   9
```

would like to create new data frame some thing like below from existing
NoofId'sin the shift = count of the id's in shift
sum of timeworked(min) on the shift = sum of the time worked in that shift

```
date       shift      sum of timeworked(min) on the shift  NoofId'sin the shift
1/1/2017     1         40                                  2
1/1/2017     2         9                                   1
1/1/2017     3         100                                 1
1/2/2017     2         30                                  1
1/4/2017     3         5                                   1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>>import pandas as pd
```

Lets call your original data frame as Dframe.
Now to add a column to the existing Dframe data frame, Serial method can be used from pandas.
Lets also call the new column to be added with the string : 'NoofId'sin the shift'

```
>>>Dframe['NoofIds in the shift']=pd.Series([2,1,1,1,1])
```

To finally display the output data frame :

```
>>>print(Dframe)
```

Comment: Expected output :